# Firebase Android foreground/background questions

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to both firebase and android and I am trying to include real-time chat in my app. But I am having the following doubts regarding firebase. Please help.

1) If the app is in foreground, will there be a default notification in the system tray or do I have to create one in onMessageReceived?

2) If the app is in background, will onMessageReceived get called?

3) If app is in background and onMessageReceived is not called, then the only way to get data is from the activity that is launched when the user clicks on the notification.
         a) What if the user doesn't click on the notification and dismisses it? How will I get the data then?
         b) Is there a way to control which activity will get called when the notification is clicked?

4)If the app is in background and onMessageReceived does get called, then what is the point of getting the data from the intent extras of the activity that is lauched?

Answer (score 1):

1)You have to create one.  There's nothing about firebase that creates notifications by default, you have to respond to an incoming message from the server in whatever way you deem appropriate.

2)So long as you're connected to Firebase, you should be called.

4)You need to ask this as a much more clear, probably independent question.  What activity?  What extras?  Anything that's done after onMessageReceived is called is totally up to you, we have no idea what you're doing with it.

Comment: @ Gabe Sechan, I went through the following links -https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive ...and in those docs, it is written that when we click on the notification, the activity is launched and we can get data from the extras of getIntent() in that activity. This is what I found confusing. Also, there is something called notification messages and they create notification by default.